# How to handle null value inside whereIn?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, laravel-query-builder

I have the following Query to be executed where `$category_id & $industry_id` came through ajax request as array. so sometimes `$category_id & $industry_id` could be  null value. So how do avoid that line of statement when the array would be null?

```
$products = DB::table('users')
               ->join('products','products.auth_id','users.id')
               ->Join('reviews','products.id','reviews.product_id')
               ->select('products.*','users.avatar',DB::raw('(sum(rating)/count(user_id)) as rating'))             
               ->orwhereIn('products.category_id', [$request->get('category_id')])   
               ->orwhereIn('products.industry_id',[$request->get('industry_id')])   
               ->where('products.status','=','1')           
               ->groupBy('reviews.product_id')   
               ->latest()              
               ->get();
```

Comment: COALESCE() is your friend

Comment: You can use if statement when value null you have skip this line and return data

Comment: Take two variable with `$category_id=array_column($request->get('category_id'));` and `$industry_id=array_column($request->get('industry_id'));` make `->when` query with where condition! It execute when category and industry is in request!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this Query does this help.

```
$query = DB::table('users')
   ->join('products','products.auth_id','users.id')
   ->Join('reviews','products.id','reviews.product_id')
   ->select('products.*','users.avatar',DB::raw('(sum(rating)/count(user_id)) as rating'))             
   ->where('products.status','=','1')           
   ->groupBy('reviews.product_id')   
   ->latest();

if ($request->has('category_id')) {
    $query->orWhereIn('products.category_id', $request->get('category_id'));
}

if ($request->has('industry_id')) {
    $query->orWhereIn(''products.industry_id', $request->get('industry_id'));
}
$products = $query->get();
```

Answer (score 0):

Simplest solution

```
    $query = DB::table('users')
       ->join('products','products.auth_id','users.id')
       ->Join('reviews','products.id','reviews.product_id')
       ->select('products.*','users.avatar',DB::raw('(sum(rating)/count(user_id)) as rating'))             
       ->where('products.status','=','1')           
       ->groupBy('reviews.product_id')   
       ->latest();

    if ($categoryId = $request->get('category_id')) {
        $query->orwhere('products.category_id', $categoryId);
    }

    if ($industryId = $request->get('industry_id')) {
        $query->orwhere('products.category_id', $industryId);
    }

    $products = $query->get();
```

BTW - changed `orWhereIn` to `orWhere` as looks like it is one value anyway.

Comment: when i tried with your solution i got following Error `strtolower() expects parameter 1 to be string, array given`

Comment: And that's not one value it's an array I'm sending, where there could be $category_id or $industry_id or both

Comment: I'm sorry, but it realy looks like one value - you are making array from it wrapping it into squeare brackets: [$request->get('category_id')]. 

Anyway - general aproach should fit.